# How to get IDs for bulk inserts in codeigniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, if I create an SQL string which does multiple inserts, how do I get the inserted id of each?

```
// Prepare the SQL
$sql = '';
$chunk = array(array(), array(), array()); // The elements are arrays
foreach($chunk as $arr){
    // The first field is the primary key (INT NOT NULL auto_increment)
    $sql .= "(NULL, {$arr[0]}, {$arr[1]}, {$arr[2]}, {$arr[3]}, {$arr[4]})";
    if($arr!= $last) $sql .= ', ';
}

// Start inserting into the db
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO my_table VALUES '.$sql);
// A few other queries go here which need the IDs of the previous insert
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

This is also my first time using transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with using transactions instead.

Comment: Can you please share how you managed go get the ids of the inserted values?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to record the MAX id before the insert, and then select all the ids greater than that after the bulk insert.

**EDIT:**

I found this in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html):

> The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with transactional tables, such as InnoDB tables, is to begin a transaction with SET autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION) followed by LOCK TABLES, and to not call UNLOCK TABLES until you commit the transaction explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible that once I get the MAX id, some other user suddenly does a similar insert before I could do my own, thus incrementing the MAX id? Is there a chance for this happening?

Comment: That's what a table lock is for

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to mysql but does that happen automatically when I make use of transactions?